# postgresql schemas conflict

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I created new database named test1, new user test1_user and i granted all on database test1 to test1_user. Moreover, I created schema test1_user. Now, I also created new schema functions_package and its owner is test1_user.

my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functions_package.newFunction(file_id     
utl_file.file_type) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
 BEGIN
 functions_package.old_function1(file_id);
 functions_package.old_function2(file_id);
 functions_package.old_function3(file_id);

 End;
 --
 $body$
 LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
 SECURITY DEFINER
 STABLE;
```

I created few functions under schema functions_package and now I`m trying to create new function that uses the old functions but im getting eror :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "functions_package"
LINE 3:    functions_package.old_function('aa');
```

I`M trying to create the new function from user test1_user;
I`m getting this error for every function in schema functions_package that i`m trying to summon in my new function. In all the old function I didnt summon any function at all so i didnt have this kind of error.
Some help ?

Comment: please provide the code that gives the error above

Comment: I updated the main post.

Comment: thank you - makes sence now

Answer (score 2):

you lack `select` before function name:
try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functions_package.newFunction(file_id     
utl_file.file_type) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
 BEGIN
 perform functions_package.old_function1(file_id);
 perform functions_package.old_function2(file_id);
 perform functions_package.old_function3(file_id);

 End;
 --
 $body$
 LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
 SECURITY DEFINER
 STABLE;
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do I need always to use perform befure i summon a function ?

Comment: yes. posrtgres does not have procedures - only functions, so you can select form frunction and select function, but need an action on it. in plpgsql when you want to select and discard the result, you use perform